# Javascript in page properties of pdf not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome

I am trying to populate a form field in a pdf file from the query string, but this isn't working in Google Chrome with the built in pdf viewer. It works fine in FF, IE, Safari & Opera.

The script, which I am trying to run is the same as can be found here:
http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/2009/12/populating_pdf_form_fields_fro.html

Comment: I don't think Chrome uses Acrobat for rendering PDF files ... it may not support JavaScript like Acrobat does.  Interesting topic.

Comment: @Pointy It can be "fixed" by disabling the built in pdf viewer (about:plugins), but still need an answer as to why javascript doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be "fixed" by disabling the built in pdf viewer (about:plugins).